# Read variables values from another file into a linux service unit file

Tags: linux, service, centos7, systemd

I have a normal looking service file in Centos7. My execStart make a call to a shell script for the service code flow.

```
ExecStart = <Path to my shell script> <var1> <var2>
```

My requirement is, rather than sending the hardcoded values of var1, var2 etc, I want to read it from a config file and use it in my service file. The config file could look like below:

```
service_config.txt:
-------------------
var1 = value1
var2 = value2
```

I must be able to read value1 and value2 from this config inside my service file.

Comment: awk '/^var1/ { print $3 }' service_config.txt

Comment: Can you add details of what did you try so far, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. Apologies for delayed post.

In the config file service_config.txt, enter key, values like below:

```
var1=value1
var2=value2
```

In the service unit file's service section,

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=<Absolute_path>/service_config.txt
```

From here on, the keys are visible using `${var1} ${var2}`